# SPARQL DELETE query Error: EOF while parsing

Tags: rdf, sparql, triplestore, triples, n-triples

I'm trying to delete some triples using this query:

`deleteQuery = """DELETE { ?a ?b ?c } WHERE { mynamespace:List mynamespace:Item ?c. 
?a ?b ?c }"""`

My namespace is already defined, so that's not an issue.
I'm not sure if I am using the correct syntax for the query though.
When I issue the query I get this error:

`400 EOF while parsing.
Expected terminals:
(prefix describe sum correlation select average modify insert median
 load ask construct clear count stats delete).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "triple_store_methods_v2.py", line 40, in query
    myResults = myTupleQuery.evaluate()
  File "/usr/local/agraph-fse-3.3/python/franz/openrdf/query/query.py", line 358, in evaluate
    response = self.evaluate_generic_query()
  File "/usr/local/agraph-fse-3.3/python/franz/openrdf/query/query.py", line 239, in evaluate_generic_query
    checkVariables=self.checkVariables, accept=accept)
  File "/usr/local/agraph-fse-3.3/python/franz/miniclient/repository.py", line 80, in evalSparqlQuery
    accept=accept)
  File "/usr/local/agraph-fse-3.3/python/franz/miniclient/request.py", line 114, in jsonRequest
    else: raise RequestError(status, body)
franz.miniclient.request.RequestError: Server returned 400: EOF while parsing.
Expected terminals:
(prefix describe sum correlation select average modify insert median
 load ask construct clear count stats delete).`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  By the way, I am using AllegroGraph 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say that Allgegrograph (at least version 3.3) does not yet support SPARQL update.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure AllegroGraph 3.x never supported SPARQL Update